# Type is not assignable to unknwon for generic function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assume a generic type

`const MyType<T> = (x: T) => void`

Consider the following situation

```
const a: MyType<string> = (x: string) => {};

const b: MyType<unknown> = a;
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'MyType<string>' is not assignable to type 'MyType<unknown>'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't unknown accept every possible type and just erase its type information?

I tried the following:

```
type MyType<T> = {x: T};

const a: MyType<string> = {x: 'hello'};

const b: MyType<unknown> = a;
```

Which works. Why are function parameters handled differently?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for might be `any` instead of `unknown`?

Comment: Any would work, but I don't understand why unknown does not work.

Comment: That happens because you have `strictFunctionTypes` enabled.

Comment: Because functions should be *contravariant* in their parameter types, as implemented in TypeScript when you enable [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types). Imagine `const a: MyType<string> = x => x.toUpperCase(); const b: MyType<unknown> = a;` followed by `b(123)`.  That would explode at runtime.  Conceptually, "something that accepts only `string`" is not assignable to "something that accepts anything". I could write up an answer when I get off mobile (assuming it's not closed as a duplicate)

Comment: MatthieuRiegler and jcalz answers make totally sense! Completely forgot about contravariant! Thank you!